# General problem solving steps when print jobs hang in AIX?

Tags: printing, aix

What should I do if jobs are getting stuck in the print queue even after restarting spooling?

```
$ stopsrc -g spooler
$ startsrc -g spooler
$ lpstat -oQUEUENAME | wc -l; sleep 30; lpstat -oQUEUENAME | wc -l
139
139

$ oslevel
6.1.0.0
```

Comment: What status does the queue have?  What status do the jobs in the queue have?

Comment: queue=down; jobs=queued

Comment: if i cancel QUEUENAME; then enable QUEUENAME then the QUEUENAME is "ready" but if i print a test page on it it goes down :D? and the test page will be a "queued" job...and it stays there forever..

Comment: I assume these are remote queues?  Can the server ping the printer/device IP address? Is the printer actually on?

Comment: ping is ok (0ms, because the ip is on one interface of the server)

Comment: this is how i print a testpage: echo 'This is just a test page.' | lp -dQUEUENAME; lpstat -oQUEUENAME

Answer (score 0):

What works in our systems is to disable the queue, make a copy of the print job, then cancel the queued job.

Once you then enable the queue, any other jobs in queue will process successfully. We then resubmit the print job that caused the hang.